# Validate prefixes of multiple columns from multiple tables in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I have tables like

Student

| ID | Clg_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1abcID | 1ae123 |
| 1abdID | 1ae123 |

College

| ID | Un_ID | Teacher_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1abcID | 1ae123 | 1afdfdf |
| 1abdID | 1ae123 | 1agfgtj |

I need to validate if all ids here starts with '1a' and return the combine result as Ids starts with given prefix or not

I tried similar approach but hard luck?

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(LTRIM(ID), 1, LENGTH(@prefix)) = @prefix THEN 1 END)
    THEN 'No Error'
    ELSE 'Error while validating prefixes'
  END AS StartsWithPrefix
FROM Student;
```

Expected result (any of below) :

1. If any 1 prefix is different than provided prefix, then return the error message.
2. If all prefixes are not same then return error.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result. I.e. provide a complete [mcve].

Comment: Which dbms are you actually using? (Remove the non-related dbms tags.)

Comment: @jarlh I'm using mysql, thanks.

Comment: So you want an error always, one of the two errors. What if the table is empty?

Comment: And the College table isn't involved?

Comment: We can Ignore the null and empty values, just need to validate all prefixes are same. I have multiple tables, and all are involved. I need combined result. @jarlh

Comment: Strange, but I can't get MySQL work here. See https://dbfiddle.uk/-13o3gDN, it works as expected when Postgresql is used, but when I switch over to MySQL I get the opposite count.